# JAVA_OPTS is not recognized

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I have the following sequences

```
ubuntu@ip-10-63-3-254:/mnt$ export JAVA_OPTS=-Dmt.config.from=En
ubuntu@ip-10-63-3-254:/mnt$ echo $JAVA_OPTS
-Dmt.config.from=En
ubuntu@ip-10-63-3-254:/mnt$ javac hello.java
ubuntu@ip-10-63-3-254:/mnt$ java hello
mt.config.from=null
ubuntu@ip-10-63-3-254:/mnt$ java -Dmt.config.from=En hello
mt.config.from=En
ubuntu@ip-10-63-3-254:/mnt$
```

where hello.java

```
public class hello {
public static void main (String[] args) {
       String property = "mt.config.from";
       String value = System.getProperty(property);
       System.out.println(property + "=" + value);
  }
}
```

Why my export JAVA_OPTS=-Dmt.config.from=En is not getting picked by hello.java? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to reference `$JAVA_OPTS` when running, e.g.:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS hello
```

I don't think `java` inspects the environmental variable at all, it's more of a convention used in scripts when firing up the jvm.

Comment: is JAVA_OPTS not an environment variable for the JVM? Why should it be referenced?

Comment: Sorry, got it. It only has affect on JVM, not program. Thanks.